# How do I move past a "Bitbake crash" when building in Yocto Toaster?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm following the instructions in Chapter 3 ("Using Toaster to Bake an Image") of [Embedded Linux Development Using Yocto Project - Third Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/product/embedded-linux-development-using-yocto-project-third-edition/9781804615065) and after starting Toaster, creating a project, and starting a build I immediately get this error:

```
Bitbake crash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 37, in <module>
    cookerdata.CookerConfiguration()))
  File "/home/joe/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/main.py", line 379, in bitbake_main
    configParams)
  File "/home/joe/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/ui/toasterui.py", line 135, in main
    params.updateToServer(server, os.environ.copy())
  File "/home/joe/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 73, in updateToServer
    ret, error = server.runCommand(["updateConfig", options, environment, sys.argv])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1170, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1342, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 656, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "<class 'xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError'>:not well-formed (invalid token): line 183, column 17">
```

I searched for this error and didn't see it mentioned anywhere. I'm stuck on what to do next.

Since you likely don't have access to the book, here is how I brought up Toaster:

1. `git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky -b kirkstone`
2. `pip3 install --user -r bitbake/toaster-requirements.txt` (from the `poky/` directory)
3. `source oe-init-build-env`
4. `source toaster start webport=0.0.0.0:8400`
5. Created a new project
6. Changed the target machine to `qemux86-64`
7. Chose the `core-image-full-cmdline` image and built it

I have successfully completed the same build (`bitbake core-image-full-cmdline`) from the command-line of the Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS machine on which I'm running Toaster.

Comment: This is using an older version of the project and there was recently a lot of work done on toaster. I'd also note that Ubuntu 18.04 is an older distro. i suspect the error is some kind of python version incompatibility and that upgrading to a newer python version/host distro would likely work around the issue. As mentioned, master has a lot of improved functionality and now is being tested in our CI so that would also likely work better. You could use buildtools tarball from the project to use a newer python too.